# Java - using recursion to create all substrings from a string

Tags: java, recursion

The following code in Java uses recursion to create all possible substrings from a string.
I am wondering is there a better way of coding this?  I want to use recursion.

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        generate("hello");
    }

    public static void generate(String word) {
        if (word.length() == 1) {
            System.out.println(word);
            return;
        }else{
            System.out.println(word);
            generate(word.substring(0, word.length()-1)); 
            generate(word.substring(1, word.length())); 
        }

    }

}
```

FAQ
Q - Why do I want to do this using recursion?
A - Because the CEO of StackOverflow says recursion is important
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/ThePerilsofJavaSchools.html

Comment: You want to use recursion and you have a working solution that uses recursion? I don't see the problem.

Comment: Looks about as efficient and clean as a recursive program of that nature should be.

Comment: Your method is fine, but another recursive way and the way I would think about it is, since your substrings are single-consecutive pieces of the main string, you're dealing with two integer variables: a starting position and an ending position. So you're essentially finding combinations thereof. For example, with the word "Hello" of length 5, you have a Starting/Ending positions of: 1/5, 2/5, 3/5, 4/5, 1/4, 2/4, 3/4, etc

Comment: @Kayaman, yes I have a working solution, just want to see if there is any better way of doing it, Im not a recursion expert.

Comment: The solution is fine once you realize that recursion is a quite bad fit for Java. This is just exercise, right? Gone are the days when recursion was taught in a language actually built for recursion: Scheme.

Comment: @Marko, yes I realize recursion is a bad fit for Java, just want to  practice recursion skills because of this http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/ThePerilsofJavaSchools.html

Comment: +1 Great article from a great writer! Yes, the Great Java Shift is what I had in mind when I wrote the above comment.

Comment: But let me give you a piece of advice: do yourself a favor and actually learn an FP language. My recommendation: Clojure. It's JVM-based, has great Java interop, and is a full-blown Scheme-like Lisp. In Clojure 90% of problems are solved using higher-order functions, they're as natural there as a `for` loop in Java.

Comment: And if you want to learn recursion, the best resource is The Little Schemer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following turned out to be the best solution:

```
public class recursive {

    static String in = "1234";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        substrings(0,1);
    }

    static void substrings(int start, int end){
        if(start == in.length() && end == in.length()){
            return;
        }else{
            if(end == in.length()+1){
                substrings(start+1,start+1);
            }else{
                System.out.println(in.substring(start, end));
                substrings(start, end+1);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

It first checks the base case: if both start and end are equal to in.length(). 
Because if they are, that means there are no more substrings to be found, and the program ends.

Let's start with start=0 and end=1. They obviously don't equal in.length(), and end definitely doesn't equal in.length()+1.
Thus, substring(0,1) will be printed out, which is 1.
The next iteration of substrings will be substrings(0,2), and in.substring(0,2) will be printed, which is 12. This will continue until end == in.length()+1, which happens when the program finishes substrings(0,4) and tries to move on to substrings(0,5).
5 == in.length()+1, so when that happens, the program will do substrings(start+1,start+1), which is substrings(1,1). The process will continue with substrings(1,2), and (1,3), until (1,5) when the program will run substrings(2,2).

All of this will continue until substrings(4,4), which, at that point, the program stops.

The result looks like this:

1
12
123
1234

2
23
234

3
34

4

Comment: well explained. Can you please explain on time & spae complexity of your solution ? will it be O(nlogn) for time ?

Comment: System.out.println(in.substring(start, end)); -- this line prints empty strings when start = end. It should be executed only when start != end, something like


`if (start != end) {
    System.out.println(str.substring(start, end));
}`

Answer (score 15):

This problem has overlapping subproblems and because of that the top-down recursion as you do is not much effective. You are evaluating multiple substrings multiple times.

Actually it is horribly ineffective (I would guess O(2^n)). Just try to run it on a bit longer string.

```
generate("OverlappingSubproblems");
```

If you are interested in a better way of solving this you can try something like this:

```
public static void generate2(String word) {
    for (int from = 0; from < word.length(); from++) {
        for (int to = from + 1; to <= word.length(); to++) {
            System.out.println(word.substring(from, to));
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use recursion you can try to rewrite the for-loops with recursion as exercise ;)

Comment: Isn't the solution you posted n^2 too?

Comment: Yes, it is n^2, but the other solution is 2^n.

Comment: Ah, got confused between the two

Comment: This solutions doesn't produce all the possible combinations of the characters in the string.

Comment: We are looking for substrings not combinations

Comment: Isn't the question asking for recursive solution?

Comment: Having a 'min length' argument would be nice, i.e. ignore generating substrings less than min length. This should be done in the loop arguments vs. a conditional in the loop body.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot to be learned from Honza's answer.I suggest you try and rewrite that as a recursive algorithm.

As with any recursive approach, divide it into self-referencing subproblems:

```
1. substrings(X) = substrings_starting_at_first_character(X) + substrings(X minus first char).
2. substrings_starting_at_first_character(X) = X + substrings_starting_at_first_character(X minus last char).
```

Next figure out your non-self-referencing base cases:

```
1. substrings("") = empty set.
2. substrings_starting_at_first_character("") = empty set.
```

And go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Another clean approach - using both looping and recursion (and does not have overlapping problem)

```
public static void printCombinations(String initial, String combined) {
    System.out.print(combined + " ");
    for (int i = 0; i < initial.length(); i++) {
        printCombinations(initial.substring(i + 1),
                combined + initial.charAt(i));

    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
        printCombinations("12345", "");
    }
```

And output is -  1 12 123 1234 12345 1235 124 1245 125 13 134 1345 135 14 145 15 2 23 234 2345 235 24 245 25 3 34 345 35 4 45 5

Comment: 14,15,.. are not substring. Your solution is giving all combinations that can be made using chars in the string...

Answer (score 0):

```
 //substring all the words from a string
  public class RecSubstring
  {
    static int c=0; 
    static void rec(String str)
    {
      if(str.equals(""))
        return;
      else
      {
        c=str.indexOf(' ');  
        System.out.println(str.substring(0,c));
        rec(str.substring(c+1));
     }
   }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    String st="We are Happy"+" " ;
    rec(st);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SubsequencesOfStr {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  String str = "abcd";
  System.out.println("0000----" + str.length());
  linearCombination(str);
 }

 static void linearCombination(String str) {
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
   int endIndex = i + 1;
   for (int j = 0; j < str.length() - i; j++) {
    System.out.println(str.substring(j, endIndex));
    endIndex++;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void allsubstring(string s,int start,int end)
{
if(start == s.size() &&  end == s.size()) {
    return;
}
else {
    if(end == s.size()) {
        allsubstring(s,start+1,start+1);
    }
    else {
        cout<<s.substr(start,end-start+1)<<endl;
        allsubstring(s,start,end+1);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

another approach using Recursion

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        subStrings("ABCDE");        
    }
    
    static void subStrings(String str) 
    {
        if(str.length()==0)
        {
            return;
        }
        subString(str);
        subStrings(str.substring(1,str.length()));
        
    }
    
    private static void subString(String str)
    {
        if(str.length()==1)
        {
            System.out.print(str+" ");
            return;
        }
        
        System.out.print(str+" ");
        subString(str.substring(0,str.length()-1));
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach employing 2 recursive functions pss and pss1 to mimic the outer and inner for loops respectively of the standard O(n^2) solution. Only this time, recursively .

output for abc : a,ab,abc,b,bc,c

```
// print substrings using recursion

void pss1 ( string s , int i , string op)
{
    // pss1 prints all substrings from a given index
 if(i==s.length()-1)
    {
        op+=s[i];
        cout<<op<<endl;
        return;
    }
     op+=s[i];
     cout<<op<<endl;
     pss1(s,i+1,op);

}
void pss ( string s , int i , string op)
{
    // pss repeats the process of pss1 for all indices by reducing the string size by 1 each time from the front (i.e) abc becomes bc at the 2nd call of psss
    if(s.length()==1)
    {
        cout<<s<<endl;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
            pss1(s,0,op);

        string S=s.substr(1);
        pss(S,0,"");

    }
    return ;
}


int main()
{
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    pss(s,0,"");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code using 1 recursive function only.

An implementation of @davidjhp's solution in c++

Analyze the Recursive stack Diagram in recursive problems to understand how the given problem is solved for smaller problems to yield the final solution.

```
// Print SubStrings using recursion 

void pss(string s, int start, int end)
{
    if(start==s.length()-1)
    {
        cout<<s.substr(start)<<endl;
        return;
    }
    if(end==s.length()+1)
    {
        start++;
        end=start+1;
        pss(s,start,end);
    }
    else if( start<=s.length()&&end<=s.length())
    {
        cout<<s.substr(start,end-start)<<endl;
        pss(s,start,end+1);
    }
}


 int main()
{
 string s;
 cin>>s;
 pss(s,0,1); 
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

/*
In Subsequence: If we take an element then we can take another element after k skips. (where k>=0)
In Substring: If we take an element then we can only take adjacent element after it. (i.e. no skips)
*/

void substring(string &s, string &res, int prevIndex, int currIndex)
{
  if(currIndex==s.size())
  {
    cout<<res<<endl;
    return;
  }
  if(prevIndex==-1 || currIndex-prevIndex==1)
  {
    res+=s[currIndex];
    substring(s,res,currIndex,currIndex+1);
    res.pop_back();
  }
  substring(s,res,prevIndex,currIndex+1);
}

int main()
{
  string s="abcde", res;
  substring(s,res,-1,0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach using recursion. It creates a sort of binary tree if you deeply understand how the code works:
(Note: The value of String ans will be set to ""(null) in the main method)

```
static void subStr(String str, String ans)    // ans="" (in main method)
{
    if(str.length() == 0){
        System.out.print(ans);
    }

    char ch = str.charAt(0);
    String ros = str.substring(1);

    subStr(ros, ans);
    subStr(ros, ans+ch);
}
```

Comment: Don't use `==` for string comparisons.

Comment: @tgdavies Okay, will use str.length()==0